# function should have a prototype

Tags: c

I am very very beginner in C programming. I am using turbo C++ 4.0, I also don't know whether it is open source or not. But I've downloaded this from internet somewhere. I've written the very simple program as following :

```
main()
{
printf("I see, I remember")
}
```

And the compiler shows the following error : 
function printf should have a prototype

And the following warning :
Function should return a value.

I am referring the book Programming in ANSI C by E. Balaguruswamy. In the book, this is the first sample program. And I just cannot run the very first program. So, please help.

Comment: First thing: Get rid of this prehistorical compiler and switch to a modern one.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Error 1: missing `#include <stdio.h>`. Error 2: `int main()`. Error 2: missing `;` after `printf()`.

Comment: Quite frankly your example is not an ANSI C. Consider using another book. [K&R](https://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628) should be better.

Comment: @EOF gcc allows to compile main function WO as is, without int or void before it, so I don't think it's an error, maybe a bad practice

Comment: @noob `gcc` is allowing many different non-ANSI-C things.

Comment: @noob: That's implementation-defined. There is absolutely no reason *not* to write `int main()`, `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, which will all work portably on any standard C-compiler.

Comment: @EOF laziness... if it works on gcc, shouldn't we at least say it is kind of OK?

Comment: @Serhio While K&R are classics, there are more recent and up to date books, better matching the existing reality..

Comment: @noob how can we, if the OP is not using GCC?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I stand corrected

Comment: Note that Turbo C++ is a ***C++*** compiler, and a very old one at that.  C++ and C are *different languages*.  C code that has been carefully designed for it can be compiled correctly by a C++ compiler, but a beginner should not be going there.  Choose a C compiler for C code.

Comment: @John Bollinger You mean, turbo C++ won't work with my commands of C? Well I've added semicolon but still these two errors are displaying.

Comment: @HardeyPandya Are you reading just the last comment?

Comment: No, I am bit confused about which compiler should I use .

Comment: @HardeyPandya `gcc` is the most commonly used one, and standard *de facto* in the open-source (but not limited to) community.

Comment: I will use this for sure. Thanks to all. But still I've question why Turbo C++ is not running this program ? (Including semicolons). Is it the matter what john bollinger told ?

Comment: @HardeyPandya, I mean that you can write valid C code that will be rejected by Turbo C++, and you can write code that is not valid C, but that Turbo C++ will accept.  You can also write valid C code that Turbo C++ accepts, but interprets differently than a C compiler would do.  All of these are bad outcomes for you if your objective is to learn C.  With care, you can also write C code that Turbo C++ will accept and interpret the same way that a C compiler would do, but that's beside the point.

Comment: Okay, @JohnBollinger. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Hardey: there are much better compilers around. Set up something with GCC or, if you really like Borland/Embarcadero, the new free clang based 32 bit C, C++ and Objective-C compiler and command line tools.It is not hard to find a freely available IDE that can be configured to use a specific C and/or C++ compiler and associated tools, these days. And they usually provide very good editors as well.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, Turbo C++ is a *very* old and discontinued development environment which does not support the latest C programming language standards.  You'd be better off using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) instead.

Secondly, the code pasted here is missing a few things; either you didn't copy it correctly, or the book you're using is not well-written.  Here's what the code *should* look like using modern C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  printf( "I see, I remember\n" );
}
```

As of the C99 language standard, implicit function declarations are no longer allowed; the compiler will no longer assume that a function returns `int` if the type isn't specified.

Also, you should not leave the parameter list for `main` empty; in this case, we're specifying that `main` takes no arguments using the `void` keyword<sup>1</sup>.

`printf` writes to standard output, and standard output is usually *line buffered*, meaning the output won't appear on your console unless you fill the buffer or send a newline character (`'\n'`).

Also as of C99, you don't need an explicit return from `main`, even though it's typed to return an integer value; by default, it will return 0 to the runtime environment when the program finishes executing.

---

1. `main` is unique in that it can either take no arguments (`int main( void )`) or two arguments (`int main( int argc, char **argv )`) for processing command-line parameters, and implementations *may* provide additional versions.

Comment: I would upvote this, but you put spaces on the inside of parentheses.  When you put spaces on the inside of parentheses you make the baby Jesus cry.  (And you did it inconsistently, which is even worse.)

Comment: Making the baby Jesus cry once is better than doing it twice, so +1

Comment: @zwol - made it consistent.  >:-)

Comment: @zwol: Blame my eyes; I have an easier time reading code formatted this way.  But I realize it's not a popular convention.

Comment: [`( "Tough Crowd Tonight" )`](https://memegenerator.net/instance/35465019)

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have the proper `#include <stdio.h>` your compiler thinks that `printf` is a function that should be declared somewhere, hence this:

> function printf should have a prototype

also, you forgot `;` at the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon(`;`) here. In C, every statement ends with a semicolon.  You are also missing a newline (\n) at the end of the string to be printed.  Your `printf` statement should look like this:

```
printf("I see, I remember\n");
```

And about the warning. Warnings are not any error, but are used to show that your code can show undefined behavior.

Use `int main()` as function name. Here, `int` is the return type of a function. `int` before `main()` means it means the function returns an integer.

So, you might wanna add `return 0;` at the end of your program as `main` function expects an `int` to return. The `return 0;` statement tells that your program has successfully completed the execution.

And also you are missing a header file `#include<stdio.h>` from which your `printf()` function definition comes. If you don't include header files, your compiler thinks that `printf()` is a function that should be declared somewhere.

Your code should look something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("I see, I remember\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this clears your doubts.

Comment: `void main()` is implementation-defined at best.

Comment: It is true that warnings are not errors, but a beginner should not use that as an excuse to ignore them.  On the contrary: a beginner is in no position to evaluate whether a given warning is safe to ignore, therefore they should fix every one.  When they have learned enough to judge, at least in some cases, whether they really need to do so, they will no longer be beginners.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know that, so I told him to add a return type to the main function in the answer.

Comment: @EOF So, we shouldn't use it? Because, I updated my answer to use `int main()`.

Comment: @VatsalSura: `main` is a special case in that you don't have to explicitly write `return 0;` to, well, return zero. C11 draft standard n1570: *5.1.2.2.3 Program termination
1
If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the
initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value
returned by the main function as its argument; 11) reaching the } that terminates the
main function returns a value of 0.* This is not to say that you *can't*  or *shouldn't* write `return 0;`, just that you don't *have to*.

Comment: Downvoted for using `getch()`-before-exiting, which is both non-portable and an antipattern.

Comment: @zwol But he is using Turbo C++ to write programs. And Turbo C++ doesn't hold the output window. So he won't be able to see the output if he doesn't write it.

Comment: @VatsalSura, it's not so much about what you know, as about what you implied.  Pointing out that warnings are not errors leaves the impression that it might be ok for the OP to ignore them.  That is inappropriate for a beginner.

Comment: @VatsalSura He should stop using Turbo C++ _anyway_, as discussed in other answers, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: @zwol Updated my answer to your point, now please remove your down vote.